# What is the asymptotic running time of

Tags: algorithm, performance

Can anyone help me check the correctness, and explain why

```
What is the asymptotic running time of T(n) = 3T(n/3) + O(n) with T(1) = 1   _______ .
```

My answer is **n<sup>log<sub>3</sub>3</sup>** .

Comment: This seems incorrect. Can you explain the reasonning behind your answer? Did you use Master Theorem?

Comment: @Olivier Melançon yes, we know a = 3, b= 3, c =3, then T(n) has running time:nlog(base3)3

Comment: Check out this link ( https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823 )
It might help you understand the Master Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misapplied the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

We have *T(n) = a T(n/b) + O(n)* where *a, b = 3*.

Since here the recurence function is *O(n)*, it takes the form *O(n<sup>c</sup> log<sup>k</sup>(n))* with *c = 1* and *k = 0*.

We are thus in the case where *c = log<sub>a</sub>(b) = 1*.

Then according to the Master Theorem, the complexity is *O(n<sup>c</sup> log<sup>k+1</sup>(n))*, that is *O(n log(n))*.